# How to be warned if RAID 1 fails on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, xubuntu, scripts, raid

Good day,

I have set up an ubuntu 10.04 LTS server with RAID 1. How can I can ensure that I am warned when the raid array fails. Is there a script to run that can check this and generate an email if there are issues?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

`mdadm` automatically sends root an email when a fault happens.  You just have to have a mail server, such as `postfix` installed on the server and configured to store or forward root's mail somewhere you will read it.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your disk is smartmon compliant by **# smartctl -i /dev/hda**

Then install smartmon # **apt-get install smartmontools**

Enable smart by editing /etc/default/smartmontools file.
Smart Configuration file: **/etc/smartd.conf**
Start/Stop smart: **/etc/init.d/smartmontools start | stop**

You can put following directives in Smart Configuration file:
(a) Send an email to marlin@yourdomain.com for /dev/sdb:

**/dev/sdb -m marlin@yourdomain.com**

(b) Read error log:
**# smartctl -l error /dev/hdb**

(c) Testing hard disk (short or long test):
**# smartctl -t short /dev/hdb**

**# smartctl -t long /dev/hdb**

Comment: Doesn't that require a postfix installation and further configuration? I remember it being a pain in the a.., but if it's running it can be a lifesaver